# How to (numerically) integrate $\int_{\tau = 0}^{\tau_1/\sqrt{10}} f(\tau)~\text{d}(\text{ln} \tau)$?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I've given the following integral

$$
\int_{\tau = 0}^{\frac{\tau_1}{\sqrt{10}}} f_k(\tau)~\text{d}(\text{ln} \tau)
$$

where $\tau_1 = 10^-3$ and $f_k(\tau)$ is given as

$$
f_k(\tau) = -\frac{(-k\tau)^k}{(k-1)!}\phi^{(k)}(k\tau)
$$

where $k$ is a given positive integer.

Function $\phi^{(k)}(x)$ is given as

$$
\phi^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}\biggl(x^{p-(k-j)}\cdot\prod_{s=1}^{k-j}(p-s+1)\biggr)\biggl((\beta + x)^{-p-j}\cdot\prod_{s=1}^{j}(-p-s+1)\biggr)
$$

where $p$ and $\beta$ are given positive numbers.

So ... I am not sure if an analytical solution of the given Integral above is possible and if, it might be quite tedious to solve it. Therefore I want to solve the given Integral numerically. Unfortunately the differential is in log-scale, so I don't know how to handle this in numerical (e.g. applying Simpson-rule).

To make it less general, I have to solve the problem for $k = 2$, $p = 0.3$ and $\beta = 750$, so the given equations become to

$$
\int_{\tau = 0}^{\frac{10^{-3}}{\sqrt{10}}} -\frac{(-2\cdot\tau)^2}{(2-1)!}\phi^{(2)}(2\tau)~\text{d}({\text{ln}\tau})
$$

and

$$
\phi^{(2)}(2\tau) = \sum_{j=0}^{2}\binom{2}{j}\biggl((2\tau)^{0.3-(2-j)}\cdot\prod_{s=1}^{2-j}(0.3-s+1)\biggr)\biggl((750 + 2\tau)^{-0.3-j}\cdot\prod_{s=1}^{j}(-0.3-s+1)\biggr)
$$

Does anyone of you can help me how to numerically integrate this? (Like by application of Simpson-rule)?

---

edit: The integral is a Stieltjes-integral. It holds:

$$
\int_a^b = f(x)\text{d}h(x) = \int_a^b = f(x)h'(x)\text{d}x
$$

if $h(x)$ is continuous differentiable. In my case it is, because $h(x) = h(\tau) = \text{ln}\tau$. Therefor, the equation becomes

$$
\int_{\tau = 0}^{\frac{\tau_1}{\sqrt{10}}}f_k(\tau)\cdot\frac{1}{\tau}\text{d}\tau
$$

and then the application of any numerical integration formula is quite clear to me.

Unfortuantely $\phi^{(k)}(0)$ leads to undefined expressions ... so here is my additional question: how to deal with that? Is there a "way round" to solve the integral?

Answer (score 1):

The inner products simplify 
$$\prod_{s=1}^{2-j}(\frac 3 {10}-s+1)=\frac{(-1)^{j}\,\Gamma \left(\frac{17}{10}-j\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(-\frac{3}{10}\right)}$$
$$\prod_{s=1}^{j}(-\frac 3 {10}-s+1)=\frac{(-1)^j \,\Gamma \left(j+\frac{3}{10}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)}$$

Now, expand the summation and use any numerical integration method.

Comment: I don't really get it ... I mean I understand the replacement of the products by Gamma-functions, but I am still struggling with, how to apply - lets say the simpson rule - on the integral. It is clear to me that $\int_a^{b}f(x)\text{d}x\approx \frac{b-a}{6}\biggl(f(a)+4f\Bigl(\frac{a+b}{2}\Bigr)+f(b)\biggr)$ but how to apply this if $\text{d}x = \text{d}(\text{ln}x)$ as in my case ... while thinking about $\text{ln}(0)=-\infty$, with respect to the lower bound $\tau = 0$. ... I really got stuck.

Comment: $\phi^{(2)}(2\tau)$ is a function within the initial integral that should be evaluated ...